# How to merge source sets while sharing dependencies to each other

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I'd like to publish a library with two different API versions where both use the same core code underneath. I tried shading/shadowing but have struggles getting the visibility right (I'd like to hide the core code from the API user). So I wanted to achieve my goals by having different source sets and configurations:

```
sourceSets {
    // the `main` source set acts as the common code base for `api` and `api2`

    api {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/api/java'
            // Includes classes from `main`:
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        }
    }
    api2 {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/api2/java'
            // Includes classes from `main`:
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    common {
        canBeResolved = true
        canBeConsumed = false
    }

    // These art the configurations used both for being consumed with `project(...)` or published:
    exposedApi {
        canBeResolved = true
        canBeConsumed = true
        extendsFrom common
    }
    exposedApi2 {
        canBeResolved = true
        canBeConsumed = true
        extendsFrom common
    }
}

task apiJar(type: Jar) {
    group = 'build'
    from configurations.exposedApi
    baseName = 'api'
}

task api2Jar(type: Jar) {
    group = 'build'
    from configurations.exposedApi2
    baseName = 'api2'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        api(MavenPublication) {
            artifact apiJar
            artifactId 'mylib-api'
        }
        api2(MavenPublication) {
            artifact api2Jar
            artifactId 'mylib-api2'
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    common sourceSets.main.output
    exposedApi sourceSets.api.output
    exposedApi2 sourceSets.api2.output
}
```

If I want to use one of these APIs I can easily use `project(path: ':mylib', configuration: 'exposedApi2')` or use one of the published Maven artifacts and it works nicely.

But as soon as I change classes in the `main` source set to `internal` in order to achieve proper encapsulation of the `main` code, the API code won't compile anymore:

```
Cannot access 'SomeClassInMain': it is internal in '' (<-- yes, it really shows nothing in the '')
```

I also tried to merge the source set into one, so there is technically not really a `main` source set anymore:

```
sourceSets {
    api {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/api/java', 'src/main/java')
        }
    }
    api2 {
        java {
            srcDirs('src/api2/java', 'src/main/java')
        }
    }
}
```

That now works all as intended, no compilation errors, calls from the API to `main` work as expected and the classes in `main` even have `internal` visibility. But unfortunately IntelliJ seems to not pick up the fact that classes in `main` are really part of the same source set. I get an error (`Unresolved reference: SomeClassInMain`) in the IDE every time I mention a class from the `main` sources and of course no auto-completion would work, too, making the solution somehow not really practical in the end.

So just to sum up the goal:

- it's important that the `main` sources are accessible to the API
- but not to the user using the API (or the Maven publication) – the only thing the user should be facing is the API
- If possible, I'd like to not put the API and main code in separate modules and publish them separately for encapsulation reasons
- I tried a shading/shadowing (fat/uber JAR) approach but I haven't managed to reduce the visibility to `internal` in the `main` sources
- I'm new to the topic of these complicated kinds of build configurations so maybe I simply have chosen the wrong approach. Maybe there's a better one which I haven't yet managed to find?

Many, many thanks in advance!